# Why does it take so long to boot?

Tags: fedora, boot, systemd, io

```
# systemd-analyze blame
       40.256s firewalld.service
       38.154s initial-setup-graphical.service
       26.161s dev-mapper-VolGroup\x2dlv_root.device
       24.262s abrtd.service
       24.118s systemd-udev-settle.service
       20.907s systemd-journal-flush.service
       17.716s accounts-daemon.service
       16.398s libvirtd.service
       11.097s systemd-udevd.service
       10.533s systemd-journald.service
       10.389s systemd-sysctl.service
       10.266s dnf-makecache.service
        4.412s polkit.service
        4.404s jexec.service
        3.767s lvm2-monitor.service
        3.439s chronyd.service
        3.300s systemd-logind.service
        3.157s livesys.service
        3.155s akmods-shutdown.service
        3.144s akmods.service
        3.143s gssproxy.service
        2.889s rpcbind.service
```

Aside from that every IO takes like forever to complete? How do I trace this?

Comment: You might want to run `smartctl`, slow I/O can be a sign of a hard disk being close to failure.

Comment: I'd look into `dmesg` first.. and thanks for introducing systemd-analyze blame!

Answer (score 4):

**Use [bootchart](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Improving_performance/Boot_process#Using_systemd-bootchart) to confirm that IO is the limiting factor in your boot process.**  I expect the graph basically shows 100% IO the whole time, and only short bursts where the CPU is fully utilized.

A quick performance test is available in GNOME Disks.  You should expect "spinning rust" to show a little better than 100MB/s, and 10ms per seek.

<del>I think the scale of timings is plausible for traditional mechanical storage.</del>  The firewalld peculiarity looks familiar.  My disk-based system takes <del>over 60</del> 90 seconds(!).  `systemd-analyze blame` doesn't look quite as bad though.

Upstream (and Fedora) developers tend to buy nice non-mechanical storage.  Performance in starting programs is a well-known benefit :-).

`systemd-readahead` was not maintained and was eventually removed.  That was the service which pre-read files required for boot in sequence, to avoid reading pages on-demand (and out of sequence).  I.e. it reduced the number of slow, mechanical operations.

I'm curious what the story is for Ubuntu.  After Ubuntu adopted systemd, I'd like to think they had enough resources to notice a large regression.

I just noticed `livesys.service`  **In case you're booting from a CD or DVD, you can expect terrible startup performance**.  For a basic USB drive... it's better, but unfortunately sequential reads won't be as fast as internal storage.

Answer (score 1):

You have likely provided your own answer in "IO takes like forever to complete". It's likely performance of your boot volume hardware that is at fault. If your I/O is super-slow, there's likely nothing you can to do to make a dramatic difference on the software side.